# Why a NSTimer can be delayed in background mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, nsrunloop, background-audio

My app run in background and uses NSTimer to launch audio after a certain amount of time. Me and my testers have no problems with this, and audio can be launched event after several hours in the background (>10h).

My issue is that some users reports that the audio is often delayed, sometimes by a few minutes, sometimes by an hour.

I do something like that:

```
UIApplication * app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
  bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:nil];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[theDateIWant timeIntervalSinceNow] target:self selector:@selector(playAudio) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    });
```

My questions are :

-Does a NSTimer can be delayed that much by the system ? if so how to go around this problem ? 
-How to reproduce this kind of issues ?
- Is it safer to use the following ?

```
theTimer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:theDateIWant interval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(playAudio) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:theTimer
                          forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Which background mode do you use?

Comment: I use background audio, and with another part in my code I manage to always have enough background execution time

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you understand background tasks a little bit wrong.

When the first snippet is performed (I assume that you place it in the `applicationDidEnterBackground` method), it says the system

> I have a small task to perform, please wait for a while till i finish
>   it!

and the system will wait for about 5-10 minutes before suspend the application.

If you need kind of alarm, you can use [LocalNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/) to playback specific sound at specified time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I said, my system already works and my users expect to hear audio event in silent mode. And I already use notifications as a secondary system. I am more concerned about delays

Comment: Actually, the timeout on current iOS versions is exactly 3 minutes.

Comment: Yes but I get around it with a loop that plays audio every 2 minutes-ish, that gives me an all new 3 minutes to run wathever

Comment: @OthmanT Sounds like a terrible app design, waiting to be rejected from the AppStore.

Comment: @LeoNatan, you'd be surprised to know how many alarm apps uses this on the app store, there is no other choice really. But that's not really my question. Thanks anyway

Comment: @LeoNatan Can a pushNotification trigger some audio from background even on silent ?

Comment: You get runtime in the background. How is that different than background runtime after silent audio playback?

Comment: @LeoNatan this runtime can't wake up your app and play audio with an AVAudioPlayer

Comment: @OthmanT "In order for AVAudioPlayer to start playing while the application is in background, your app must support remote control events." http://sapandiwakar.in/switch-to-a-new-song-in-background-for-ios/

Comment: @LeoNatan, thanks, this is interesting!  But I still have to manage without having to setup a notification server. Can this be achieved with a local notification ?

Comment: No. Local notifications do not allow background execution time.

Comment: @LeoNatan, would you be available to discuss some of this issue via mail or something ? that would help me a lot arrange some of my architecture flaws

Comment: Sure, you can find my contact information in my profile.